# How do I cast a variable to the same type of a dynamic variable?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, dynamic, casting

I'm currently working on an amplification method that accepts PCM samples as an `ICollection<dynamic>` (the caller will only pass a collection of either: `sbyte`, `short` or `int`). The amplification algorithm I've created works fine; it's just I'm not sure how to convert the newly amp'ed samples back to their original type, since the amplification logic outputs the samples as a `List<double>`.

I'm aware I could add some sort of `switch` statement to cast the samples back to their original type, but this seems like a rather primitive solution, is there a better method to accomplish this?

How I'm calling the method (`samples` is a `List<dynamic>` contining `int`s, `file` is class I've created for reading wav files),

```
AmplifyPCM(samples, file.BitDepth, 0.5f);
```

My method,

```
static private List<dynamic> AmplifyPCM(ICollection<dynamic> samples, ushort bitDepth, float volumePercent)
{
    var highestSample = 0;
    var temp = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (var sample in samples)
    {
        if (sample < 0)
        {
            temp.Add(-sample);
        }
        else
        {
            temp.Add(sample);
        }
    }

    foreach (var sample in temp)
    {
        if (sample > highestSample)
        {
            highestSample = sample;
        }
    }

    temp = null;

    var ratio = (volumePercent * (Math.Pow(2, bitDepth) / 2)) / highestSample; 
    var newSamples = new List<dynamic>();

    foreach (var sample in samples)
    {
        newSamples.Add(sample * ratio); // ratio is of type double, therefore implicit conversion from whatever sample's type is to a double.
    }

    // switch statement would go here if there's no better way.

    return newSamples;
}
```

Comment: You could just make the method generic, won't that work for you?

Comment: @ToughCoder I hadn't thought of using generics, yeah I guess that would solve the problem. Thanks. D'you want to write up an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can just make it generic that will give the return type. But operators with generics are not supported in C#. You can try casting them as dynamic.

```
static private List<T> AmplifyPCM<T>(ICollection<T> samples, ushort bitDepth, float volumePercent)
{
    var highestSample = 0;
    var temp = new List<T>();

    foreach (var sample in samples)
    {
        if ((dynamic)sample < 0)
        {
            temp.Add(-(dynamic)sample);
        }
        else
        {
            temp.Add(sample);
        }
    }

    foreach (var sample in temp)
    {
        if ((dynamic)sample > highestSample)
        {
            highestSample = (dynamic)sample;
        }
    }

    temp = null;

    var ratio = (volumePercent * (Math.Pow(2, bitDepth) / 2)) / highestSample;
    var newSamples = new List<T>();

    foreach (var sample in samples)
    {
        newSamples.Add((dynamic)(T)sample * ratio);
    }

    return newSamples;
}
```

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on a `T`. Things like `sample < 0` and `-sample` won't compile. There's also no way to say, e.g. `where T : number` to allow such things, which may be why the method had `dynamic to start with.

Comment: @TimS. I didn't check the code on Visual Studio. Let me check it and I will update my answer.

Comment: Ah yes I've just checked it out, I thought there was a reason why I didn't use generics, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think to combine the two.

Comment: @Sam you can create IArithmetic interface to cast int, double types but it is too much hassle. Check this Jon Skeet's link for generic operators: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html